# Fetching the function names from module in python

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, operating-system

for doing --  from audit.status import status
where, "status" in audit.status is the module name and the last "status" is class name.

i am using `__import__` as,

```
temp = __import__ ("audit.status"), globals=(), locals=(), fromlist=["status"]

classname = temp.status
```

And its working well, but how can i use the modulename i have fetched using above method in the below statement to fetch the function names:

[obj for obj in getmembers(module_name) if isfunction(obj[1])]

Comment: Where are `getmembers` and `isfunction` defined? Do you have any `import` statements you haven't shown us? Please show us all the import statements you haven't shown us.

Comment: from inspect import getmembers, isfunction

Comment: Please edit your question rather than answering in a comment

Comment: i am not answering in comments....my question is very clear...i am just replying to these ppls cooments

Comment: Incidentally, `inspect.isfunction` returns False for both built-in functions and for class methods. This is not entirely apparent from the documentation.

Comment: I want to dynamically import the module, fetch its class name and run the methods inside the class

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking "how can I find all of the callable attributes of a module object?",

```
>>> import math
>>> attrs = [getattr(math, name) for name in dir(math)]
>>> callables = [attr for attr in attrs if hasattr(attr, "__call__")]
>>> print callables
[<built-in function acos>, <built-in function acosh>, <built-in function asin>,
...
<built-in function tan>, <built-in function tanh>, <built-in function trunc>]
```

Or if you just want the names and not the attributes themselves,

```
>>> names = [name for name in dir(math) if hasattr(getattr(math, name), "__call__")]
>>> print names
['acos', 'acosh', 'asin', ... 'tan', 'tanh', 'trunc']
```

Comment: There is something wrong i am doing while passing the module name to getmembers()....because it gives me empty list of functions.

Comment: I don't know what `getmembers` is, but you don't need to use it. My answer doesn't require `getmembers` anywhere.

Comment: i tried, [method for method in dir(classname) if callable(getattr(cname,method))]  But this gives me list of all the attributes such as "__class__", "__format__" and also methods of the class itself along with the methods and attributes of parent class... is there a way i can filter this out to get only the methods of the classname i am providing

Comment: Make sure that you're supplying the module object rather than the module name, everywhere that you're replacing "math" with your module. Otherwise, you'll just be inspecting the `string` class.